# Почему элементы, появляются секунд через 3-5 после загрузки страницы?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, скорость, pagespeed

Работаю сейчас над этим сайтом:
https://evroflag.by/category-product/flagshtoki-i-konstrukcii-dlya-flagov/mobilnye-flagshtoki

И вот, ломаю голову, почему вот эти элементы, появляются секунд через 3-5 после загрузки страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скорость у сайта нормальная.

Откуда этот баг и как его ликвидировать?

Comment: У меня все сразу появляется.

Comment: @Simon почему-то на разных машинах, оно появляется то с задержкой 3-5 секунд, на других около 10 секунд. У некоторых сразу. Отчего бы это?

Comment: Да, в хроме действительно есть некая задержка.

Comment: @Simon из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Причина явно в джеесе, но точнее сказать сложно, нужно смотреть что там, тем более тема Themeforest с билдером и кучей всего под капотом.

Answer (score 1):

Queueing time огромное для изображений. На картинке - 1.6 секунды.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Читаем пояснения по ссылке Explanation внизу справа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрим используемый протокол:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если хостер не в состоянии обеспечить http/2.0, где нет ограничений на число соединений - бегите от этого хостера.